# How to pass image file with variable value in ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on PHP and AJAX to upload image in a folder and message value(any textbox and textarea value).
The code is working for image upload by ajax and PHP but I don't know how to pass message variable value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <span id="msg" style="color:red"></span><br/>
     <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message"></textarea>
    <input type="file" id="photo"><br/>
     <button class="btn btn-success" id="save">Save</button>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "#save", function () {
         var message = $("#message").val();
        var property = document.getElementById('photo').files[0];
        var image_name = property.name;
        var image_extension = image_name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

        if(jQuery.inArray(image_extension,['gif','jpg','jpeg','']) == -1){
          alert("Invalid image file");
        }

        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append("file",property);
        $.ajax({
          url:'insert2.php?'+message,
          method:'POST',
          data:form_data,
          contentType:false,
          cache:false,
          processData:false,
          beforeSend:function(){
            $('#msg').html('Loading......');
          },
          success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#msg').html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The image is uploading in a folder but the message is undefined when I click save button .

```
<?php
if($_FILES['file']['name'] != ''){
    $test = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $extension = end($test);    
    $name = rand(100,999).'.'.$extension;

    $location = 'testimg/'.$name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location);

    echo '<img src="'.$location.'" height="100" width="100" />';
    echo $message = $_POST['message'];
}
  
?>
```

It's giving me undefine message value on the PHP page.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkgOb.png)

What is the best way to pass file and box values using ajax for PHP file?

Comment: If you put your form elements in an actual form, you can pass it in when you create your FormData object `var form_data = new FormData(document.querySelector('#theFormId'));`, you'll get a FormData object that contains all elements in that form (including files). Otherwise, you should be able to just append again: `form_data.append('message', message)`

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to do that like- data: {message: message}, with type file upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['message']` is not defined because you didn't put a property called `message` in the FormData object. You can't expect something to exist in the POST variables if you didn't submit it to the server in the first place.

You simply need to add it to the form data:

```
form_data.append('message', message);
```

Also

```
url:'insert2.php?'+message
```

makes no sense (because it doesn't create a valid querystring). Change it to just

```
url:'insert2.php?'
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do that like- data: {message: message}, with type file upload?

Comment: No. You must use formdata. But so what? Why does the syntax of the data object matter to you? It's a trivial detail. The important thing is to make it work, and this is how you make it work for file uploads.

Comment: @Shiva If you have a new question, please post a new question. If you link to it here, I would be happy to take a look. Expanding your existing questions endlessly is not really how this site works. Otherwise existing answers can start to be stale and/or no longer make sense as the question gets edited, and also people (both questioners and answerers) are unable to gain reputation despite providing more time, effort and information. Question editing is for the purpose of adding extra information about the existing question, not adding new questions or strands. Thanks :-)